# Strange //! comment syntax in Quick Controls 2.0 QML source

Tags: qt, qml, comments, qtquickcontrols2

While looking through Quick Controls 2.0 sources, I came upon a peculiar comment syntax that I can't seem to find in docs:

```
//! [property]
property: ...
...
//! [property]
```

for example, pairs of `//! [contentItem]`, `//! [background]` could be seen in `TabButton.qml`.

---

I wonder if this is just a convention chosen by the developers to delimit regions of code, or does it indeed have some special meaning?

Comment: Yep, definitely a duplicate... But to my defense, I surely did try to find an answer before asking. Any recommendations on how do I search for short strings on SO (as well as google them)? Searching `[qml] "//!"` gave me zero results.

Comment: I didn't find it either ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Qt comments that begin with `!` are parsed to generate documentation. That applies to single and multi line comments.

In this particular case however it doesn't seem to contain any actual documentation, it is used to signify the lines where individual implementation details begin and end.

You can learn more about the documentation format [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoc-guide-writing.html).

Answer (score 3):

There used to be example code snippets on the [Customizing Qt Quick Controls](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html)  documentation page, that were automatically extracted from our own QML code with help of those qdoc-markers.