# Semantic of "// ![0]" in QML examples

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

In many QML Examples you can find the line:

```
// ![0]
```

See:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-tutorials-samegame-samegame4-example.html#adding-particle-effects
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-extended-example-qml.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-animation-states-transitions-qml.html

It clearly is a comment.

But since the text of the comment does not seem to carry any meaning but appears frequently, I was wondering if there is any deeper meaning to it, like a *shebang* line is a comment, too, but carries meaningful information for the interpreter.

Is this some kind of annotation for the QML translator or maybe just some comment the author thought, it will carry a clear message to the reader?

Comment: Just a guess: maybe it is related to [QDoc](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qdoc-guide-writing.html) ?

Comment: Ok, to summarize the answers from the [question it duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347224/strange-comment-syntax-in-quick-controls-2-0-qml-source) and the [question it really duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508413/0-in-qt-source-code): `\\!` starts a comment for QDoc. `\\ ![n]` specifically has been for a feature of QDoc to automatically render the enclosed excerpts of the code in the documentation. This feature might be obsolete. (jpnumri: "[...] *used* to be example code [...]", link to code implementing the feature is dead.)